# Can we Vote to Close a question, whilst also generating a comment automatically?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

If I Vote to Close a question as a duplicate, I think I'm right in saying that the site will automatically generate a comment on the question - possible duplicate of blah-blah-blah.

I was just wondering whether it is possible (or indeed a good idea) to auto-generate comments for some other reasons?

The particular reason I had in mind is a product rec. One question just came up which is an obvious example of something falling foul of this - [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/23270/cannondale-marin-and-specialized-mountain-bike-comparison).

It was a no-brainer for me to vote to close this, but it seems rude not to add a comment as to why. Especially as in this case, the user is new to the site. So I searched through and found one of @jimirings comments, and just copied and pasted - no big deal but not trivial as I had to copy the links too.

But it would have been nice if I hadn't had to go searching. Even if the site were to give me a checkbox to add a comment, with some default text proposed (pkay, I'm guessing this may not be supported).

So, can it be done and would it be a good idea to do so? As I say, I wouldn't propose this for all reasons, but I do think there are some that fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

Once the question actually gets closed with that close reason, the "on hold" message does show up with exactly the explanation you want.

Comment: so that then tends to support saying nothing (and hoping that sufficient of us agree to close it). Fair enough I guess, its just that showing the message earlier would at least give the Op a chance to put the question right. But I guess they can always ask a fresh question.

Comment: I generally put a comment in manually if there's not an auto one showing up immediately. And sometimes the user comes back straight away and edits the question into shape, so that can work.